# In given figure, prove

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, two chords $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at right angles at $X$. Prove that $\text{arc } AD - \text{arc } CA =\text{arc }BD - \text{arc } BC$

[image]

**My Attempt:**

Join $AC$ and $AD$

$1. \quad \angle CAB+\angle ACD=\angle AXD$

$2. \quad \angle DAB +\angle ADC=\angle AXC$.

$3. \quad \angle AXC=90^{\circ}$

What should I do next?  Please complete the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\angle AOD=2\angle ACD$$
$$\angle AOC=2\angle ADC$$
$$\angle BOD=2\angle BAD$$
$$\angle BOC=2\angle BAC$$
$$\angle ACD+\angle BAC=\angle BAD+\angle ADC=90^{\circ}$$
$$\therefore \quad \angle ACD-\angle ADC=\angle BAD-\angle BAC$$
$$\therefore \quad \angle AOD-\angle AOC=\angle BOD-\angle BOC$$
$$\therefore \quad \operatorname{arc} AD-\operatorname{arc} AC
= \operatorname{arc} BD-\operatorname{arc} BC$$

[image]

Comment: how did you get that point $O$?

Comment: It's circumcentre.  The angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference.

Comment: Is it the actual point or just an assumption?  I guess it has not been provided by the question.

Comment: You can't avoid it, since you need convert angle to arc.

Comment: What does it mean

Comment: The point $O$ always exists (and constructible) no matter it's drawn or not.  But you need it for your proof.  Revise your geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Using this standard result:

$$\angle AXD = \frac{\operatorname{arc}AD+\operatorname{arc}BC}{2}$$

we also get

$$\angle AXC = \frac{\operatorname{arc}AC+\operatorname{arc}BD}{2}$$

but $\angle AXD=\angle AXC=90$, so

$$\frac{\operatorname{arc}AD+\operatorname{arc}BC}{2}=\frac{\operatorname{arc}AC+\operatorname{arc}BD}{2}$$
$$\operatorname{arc}AD+\operatorname{arc}BC=\operatorname{arc}AC+\operatorname{arc}BD \Rightarrow \operatorname{arc}AD-\operatorname{arc}AC=\operatorname{arc}BD-\operatorname{arc}BC$$

Comment: How is $$\angle AXD = \frac{\operatorname{arc}AD+\operatorname{arc}BC}{2}$$
?

Comment: That is a very standard result: angle formed by two intersecting chords. See the item number 4 here: http://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/CRAngles.html